# Finding and getting line in XML with specific atribute in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, attributes

I have problem with getting string from XML which contains:

```
<label lang=
```

These phrases can be standing alone or with another attributes. For example:

```
<result>
    <label lang="EN">Result</label>
</result>
```

Or

```
<refusal>
    <label lang="EN">Refused</label>
    <desc lang="EN" />
</refusal>
```

What I need is to get **full line with label phrase.**
I'm using now XDocument from LINQ in C# and right now I'm able just to get inside of it. In previous example it's:

> Refused

Comment: So you want `<label lang="EN">Refused</label>`?

Comment: @dominosam Please add the code where you are using Linq to XML!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to get every item isnide your "result" tag and check if it has an attribute called lang. If so, print the whole thingy (for example `<label lang="EN">Refused</label>`)

```
XmlNodeList aNode = xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("result");
XmlNodeList bNode = aNode[0].ChildNodes;

foreach (XmlNode item in bNode)
{
    try
    {
        string s = item.Attributes["lang"].OuterXml;
    }
    catch
    {
        //the item doesn't have the attribute lang
    }
}
```

I would approach this problem like this. If the node doesn't contain the Attribute it would throw an error, which I handle with `try` and `catch`

If you need further help or Explanation please leave a comment

XmlNode has several nice ways to get the text of the item, for example `InnerText`, `InnerXml` or `OuterXml`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the example:

```
   var text = @"<refusal>
        <label lang=""EN"">Refused</label>
        <desc lang=""EN"" />
    </refusal>";
   var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(text);
   var elements = xdoc.Root.Elements()
       .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "label" && x.Attributes().Any(a => a.Name.LocalName == "lang" && a.Value == "EN"));
   Console.WriteLine(elements.First().ToString()); // Output: <label lang="EN">Refused</label>
```

Note it's not checking the element namespace (I'm not sure you need that), so elements like "" will be included as well.